# How to check an object in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been working in these codes and I had a problem in the part when the user will input a value he/she want to check if it's in the array or not.

How to check an object in an array in Java?

```
public static void main (String args []) 
{
    String sInput1,sInput2,sLetters,s;
    int iInput1,i1,i2;
    boolean b1 = true;

    sInput1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of values in the array:");
    iInput1 = Integer.parseInt (sInput1);
    String Arr1[] = new String [iInput1];

    for (i1=0;i1<iInput1;i1++)
    {
        Arr1[i1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the values:");
        System.out.println("You entered " + Arr1[i1] + ".");
    }

    sInput2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value you want to check in the array:");

    for (i1=0;i1<iInput1;i1++)
    {
        if (Arr1[i1].equals(sInput2))
        {
            b1=true;
        }
        else
        {
            b1=false;
        }
        if (b1 == true)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The value you want to check is in the array.","RESULT!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The value you want to check is not in the array.","RESULT!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: You have to search through the whole array, now you are only searching until the value that is given as input. Unless your array is sorted that is not going to work.

Comment: Did you notice how the title of your question does not mention Swing in any form?  That's a good hint that Swing has nothing to do with the problem, and should not be added as a tag!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
b1 = Arrays.asList(Arr1).contains(sInput2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must initialise `b1` as `false`:

```
boolean b1 = false;
```

Then your can do the check:

```
for (i1 = 0; i1 < iInput1 && !b1; i1++)
    if (Arr1[i1].equals(sInput2))
        b1 = true;
```

And, in the end, print out the result:

```
if (b1)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The value you want to check is in the array.", "RESULT!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The value you want to check is not in the array.", "RESULT!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Or, shortly:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The value you want to check is" + (b1 ? " " : " not ") + "in the array.", "RESULT!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: You should add a `break` statement if the searched value was found.

Comment: Yes, this wouldn't change the complexity, always O(n), but sometimes could help. However, I prefer to change the condition in the `for` cycle in this way: `for (i1 = 0; i1 < iInput1 && !b1; i1++)`.

Comment: Well, if you prefer to "hide" an additional check in the `for` loop, then do it. Since it is pretty uncommon, it could be easily missed.

Comment: It depends on what's your programming style. `break` are good but should be avoided as much as possible. The rules of "good programming" suggest to have only one entry and exit point in cycles and methods.

Comment: `break are good but should be avoided as much as possible.` Cool, so instead of writing a `break` you're writing all exit conditions in the for loop? I'm sure, this is very readable. But you're right, it depends on the own programming style, so there is no point in discussion this here.

Comment: Of course not. If conditions are more than two or at most three, I'll use a `break`. Readability first of all!

Comment: Well and I prefer only one termination condition in the `for` loop and this is mostly connected with the iteration variable. I guess this structure that (almost) everyone uses and *expects*. An additional termination condition could be easily missed there. A `break` is more verbose at this point. You're right, one shouldn't use too many return statements, but the "rule" of only one is too rigorous, especially if you prefer to "fail (or return) early".